# How to trigger specific Google Custom Search Engine refinement label?

Tags: google-custom-search

Currently, our organization is using Google Custom Search engine to provide auto suggestion, and we have about 3 refinement labels configured in our CSE. Previously, we're using WebSearch and SearchControl, and the WebSearch has a setSiteRestriction method which allows us to specifically select a refinement label:
- http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/docs/reference.html#_class_GwebSearch

Previous code example:

```
var searchControl = new google.search.SearchControl();

var webSearch = new google.search.WebSearch();

//Refinement allows us to tell Google which specific sites to search
var refinement="Support";    
//filter custom search and currently there are 3 refinements
(some other variables declaration here including 'product')
switch(product)

{

    case "10000":
        refinement = "Support1";
        break;

    case "10200":
        refinement = "Support1";
        break;

    case "10001":
        refinement = "Support2";
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

/*this is the code to fill in the custom search. The refinement was set above - either "Support", "Support1", or "Support2".*/
webSearch.setSiteRestriction('cseId', refinement);
......
```

However, currently we're migrating to CustomSearchControl tool to replace the deprecated WebSearch, but apparently I couldn't find any way to specifically select a refinement label based on the value of switch case statement. Immediate help needed here, and if there's a relevant docs that you guys can point me to will be much appreciated. thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer. Appended the following lines to the code:

```
var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl(cseId);
customSearchControl.setSearchStartingCallback(this, function(control, searcher, query) 
{
      searcher.setQueryAddition('more:' + refinement);
});
```

Comment: This *almost* works... you can do this or just do 

customSearchControl.execute(yourQuery + ' more:' + refinement)

However, it doesn't highlight the refinement tab to tell the user what you did on their behalf.  Investigating, maybe I'll file a bug.

Answer (score 3):

When using customSearchControl, you can set the refinement label in the options.
This will

> a) not restrict other refinements in your search to the keywords you
> may have added with ('more: ' + refinement), and
>
> b) also highlight
> the refinement tab to tell the user what you did on their behalf.

```
var customSearchOptions =
    { 'defaultToRefinement' : 'refinement_label_name' };

  var customSearchControl =
    new google.search.CustomSearchControl('YOUR_CSE_ID', customSearchOptions);
```

The defaultToRefinement parameter is mentioned in the Custom Search Element [JavaScript API Reference](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/customsearch/docs/js/cselement-reference.html).

Previously, this answer was introduced [here](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!msg/customsearch/xoW14I-fJnk/Gry9kpEwCCcJ).