# Write one billion files in one Folder BUT "(No space left on device)" error

Tags: c, linux, tcp, filesystems, client-server

I'm trying to write 1 billion of files in one folder using multi thread but next my program wrote 20 million files I got "No space left on device". I did not close my program because It still writing same files.

- I don't have any problems with "inode", I used only 7%.
- No problem with /tmp, /var/tmp, there are empty.
- I increased fs.inotify.max_user_watches to 1048576.

I use debian and EXT4 as filesystem.
Is there same one meet this problem and thank you so much for help.

Running `tune2fs -l /path/to/drive` gives

```
Filesystem features: has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize

Filesystem flags: signed_directory_hash

Default mount options: user_xattr acl

Filesystem state: clean

Errors behavior: Continue

Filesystem OS type: Linux

Inode count: 260276224

Block count: 195197952

Reserved block count: 9759897

Free blocks: 178861356

Free inodes: 260276213

First block: 0

Block size: 4096

Fragment size: 4096

Reserved GDT blocks: 1024

Blocks per group: 24576

Fragments per group: 24576

Inodes per group: 32768

Inode blocks per group: 2048

Flex block group size: 16

Filesystem created: ---

Last mount time: ---

Last write time: ---

Mount count: 2

Maximum mount count: -1

Last checked: ---

Check interval: 0 ()

Lifetime writes: 62 GB

Reserved blocks uid: 0 (user root)

Reserved blocks gid: 0 (group root)

First inode: 11

Inode size: 256

Required extra isize: 28

Desired extra isize: 28

Journal inode: 8

Default directory hash: ---

Directory Hash Seed: ---

Journal backup: inode blocks
```

Comment: There is a limit to the number of files per directory, which depends on parameters given when the file system was created. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537471/what-is-the-max-files-per-directory-in-ext4), too.

Comment: Yes there is a limitation when I work with ext3 but EXT4 is unlimited.

Comment: What is your EXT4 block size and bytes/inode (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154841/))? What does `df -h` and `df -i` tell you?

Comment: -When I run df -i or df -h there is not partition use more than 20%.
-I did not use inodes, I set it to 200M.
-file size = 2 bytes

Comment: What about output from `tune2fs -l /path/to/drive`? Note that actually posting the output from these commands in your question may be helpful (it may look fine to you but someone could see something you don't).

Answer (score 0):

check this question
 [How to store one billion files on ext4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397110/how-to-store-one-billion-files-on-ext4)

you have fewer blocks than inodes which is not going to work, though I think that is the least of your problems. If you really want to do this (would a database be better?) you may need to look into filesystems other an ext4 `zfs` springs to mind as an option that allows 2^48 entries per directory and should do what you want.

If this question https://serverfault.com/questions/506465/is-there-a-hard-limit-to-the-number-of-files-a-directory-can-have is anything to go by, there is a limit on the number of files per directory using ext4 which you are likely hitting