# How do you change the default refinement label in google cse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-custom-search

I've been looking everywhere for a method that changes the default tab "All" into a label of one's choosing in the search results.

So far this is what I found, from "[How to trigger specific Google Custom Search Engine refinement label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154841/how-to-trigger-specific-google-custom-search-engine-refinement-label)", but I don't think it's for my specific purpose.

```
var customSearchOptions =
{ 'defaultToRefinement' : 'refinement_label_name' };

var customSearchControl =
    new google.search.CustomSearchControl('YOUR_CSE_ID', customSearchOptions);
```

I also stumbled upon a post, with an unrelated topic, that seemed to have accomplished it - just run the code snippet and click the search button to see what I mean:[Google site search catch search submit and trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524620/google-site-search-catch-search-submit-and-trigger-function) - I've played around with it and found that it relates to engine ID which is: '017643444788069204610:4gvhea_mvga' in that example.

How can you change the default 'all' tab into something else while still being able to have other tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have solved this problem with CSS.

```
div > div.gsc-tabHeader:nth-child(1) {
    visibility: hidden;
}

div > div.gsc-tabHeader:nth-child(1):after {
    content: "Insert_NewTab_Name";
    visibility: visible;
}

.gsc-tabHeader.gsc-tabhActive:after {
    border: 1px solid Insert_border_color;
    border-bottom-color: #fff !important;
    padding: 7px;
    visibility: visible;
}
```